# vb.net delegates don't seem to be working

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

In VB.net, I am trying to use delegates to update a control on a form from a thread, however it doesn't change anything on the form. I've confirmed that it is,in fact, receiving data(so it's not blank), but for some reason it won't send that data to the control.

```
Delegate Sub fupdatedelegate(ByVal itemtoadd As String)
Dim myupdate As fupdatedelegate = AddressOf updatefrmlist

Private Sub updatefrmlist(ByVal itemtoadd As String) 
    With Form1.ListBox1.Items
        .Add(itemtoadd)
    End With
    MsgBox(itemtoadd)
End Sub
```

and called as

```
If Form1.ListBox1.InvokeRequired Then
   Form1.ListBox1.BeginInvoke(myupdate)
End If
```

how can I make it so that it actually adds the items to the `ListBox`? (this is being run from a module)

Comment: Standard VB.NET trap, you cannot use "Form1" here.  When the code runs on a worker thread then you get a *new* instance of the Form1 class.  One that is not visible since its Show() method was never called.  And one whose InvokeRequired property returns *False*.  You *must* write proper object-oriented code and use the correct object reference.  Which is the Form1 object that the user is actually looking at.  You can use Application.OpenForms(0).BeginInvoke() if you are desperate.

Comment: @HansPassant: +1 for that - I've seen too many problems due to VB developers using the default form instance without even realizing what they're doing. VB has too many 'features' which can really allow you to shoot your foot off.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the sub to deal with the invoke.  Then just call it with the item to add.

```
Private Sub updatefrmlist(ByVal itemtoadd As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(myupdate, itemtoadd)
    Else
        With ListBox1.Items
            .Add(itemtoadd)
        End With
        ' MsgBox(itemtoadd)
    End If
End Sub
```

All calls will look like

```
 updatefrmlist(somestring)
```

Comment: for some reason, it won't accept me writing "me" there.

Comment: in a module- should it be part of the class?

Comment: Moving it to the form class will fix the problem.